# Repeatable Annotation Interfaces

Tags: java, annotations

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3) states:

> ```
> import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
> import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
> import java.lang.annotation.Target;
>
> @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
> @Repeatable(FooContainer.class)
> @interface Foo {}
>
> @Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
> @interface FooContainer {
>     Foo[] value();
> }
> ```
>
> `@Foo` can appear on any class or interface declaration while `@FooContainer` can appear on only annotation interface declarations. Therefore, the following annotation interface declaration is legal:
>
> ```
> @Foo @Foo
> @interface Anno {}
> ```
>
> while the following interface declaration is illegal:
>
> ```
> @Foo @Foo
> interface Intf {}
> ```

I don't understand why the latter one is illegal.

Answer (score 2):

Because `@Foo @Foo` is actually `@FooContainer({@Foo, @Foo})` and `@FooContainer` is only allowed on annotation types, not on interfaces (as declared by `@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)`).

`@Foo` itself is only valid on types (`@Target(ElementType.TYPE)`), which includes annotation types. Annotations can always be used without their container annotation, but different targets might apply.

Comment: Does it mean that single Foo annotation can be applied to class / interface, but multiple Foo annotations can be applied only to annotations ?

Comment: @Gosia Yes. The container annotation is only present if more than one of the repeatable annotation is declared. If you have only one `@Foo` then `@FooContainer` is not involved.